# How can I get all of a few users' roles?

Tags: oracle

I need to see all of a user's roles, including the roles inherited from a role.

Consider for example, this arrangement:

```
CREATE USER TEMPUSER1 IDENTIFIED BY "TEMPUSER1" ACCOUNT LOCK;
CREATE USER TEMPUSER2 IDENTIFIED BY "TEMPUSER2" ACCOUNT LOCK;

CREATE ROLE TEMP_ROLE1;
CREATE ROLE TEMP_ROLE2;
CREATE ROLE TEMP_ROLE3;
CREATE ROLE TEMP_ROLE4;
CREATE ROLE TEMP_ROLE5;

GRANT TEMP_ROLE1 TO TEMP_ROLE3;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE2 TO TEMP_ROLE3;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE3 TO TEMP_ROLE4;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE3 TO TEMP_ROLE5;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE4 TO TEMP_ROLE6;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE5 TO TEMP_ROLE6;

GRANT TEMP_ROLE2 TO TEMPUSER1;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE4 TO TEMPUSER1;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE6 TO TEMPUSER1;
GRANT TEMP_ROLE2 TO TEMPUSER2;
```

Then I want the result

```
GRANTED_USER   | GRANTED_ROLE
---------------+---------------
TEMPUSER1      | TEMP_ROLE1
TEMPUSER1      | TEMP_ROLE2
TEMPUSER1      | TEMP_ROLE3
TEMPUSER1      | TEMP_ROLE4
TEMPUSER1      | TEMP_ROLE5
TEMPUSER2      | TEMP_ROLE1
TEMPUSER2      | TEMP_ROLE2
```

I'm using Oracle 11.2g, but I also want answers for future versions of Oracle. I'd like for this question to remain relevant if Oracle introduces new features that make this easier (like a view that just gives this to us straight up without writing our own queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

The view that tells us about `GRANT`ed roles is [`DBA_ROLE_PRIVS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5406.htm). (There's also [`USER_ROLE_PRIVS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5406.htm), but it only shows roles granted to the current user.) However, this view does not give us all the inherited roles. Following through the user's roles recursively requires a ["hierarchical" query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315), or more simply known as a recursive query.

- Logically, we want to start with roles granted to the user directly. This means that our `START WITH` clause should ensure that `GRANTEE = 'TEMPUSER1'`.
- Then we want to look at rows where the `GRANTEE` is one of the roles granted to the user of interest so far. This means our `CONNECT BY` clause should ensure that `PRIOR GRANTED_ROLE = GRANTEE`.
- To carry through the actual user through to the rows in our result set, we need to include `CONNECT_BY_ROOT GRANTEE`, which will give us the `GRANTEE` from the starting rows (and we started with our user of interest).
- Last, it's possible for a user to inherit a role through two different roles, as exemplified with how `TEMP_ROLE6` inherits `TEMP_ROLE3`. This means we'll need some kind of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.

## The query

Assembling all that into a query gives us:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONNECT_BY_ROOT GRANTEE AS GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE
FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
START WITH GRANTEE IN ('TEMPUSER1', 'TEMPUSER2')
CONNECT BY GRANTEE = PRIOR GRANTED_ROLE
ORDER BY GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE
;
```

This gives the exact result desired.

---

**Bonus info: Source of role**

Here's an alternate query that includes some extra info about how the user got the role:

```
SELECT GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE, LISTAGG(DIRECT_GRANTEE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DIRECT_GRANTEE) AS ROLE_SOURCE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT CONNECT_BY_ROOT GRANTEE AS GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE, REPLACE(GRANTEE, CONNECT_BY_ROOT GRANTEE, 'Direct GRANT') AS DIRECT_GRANTEE
    FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
    START WITH GRANTEE IN ('TEMPUSER1', 'TEMPUSER2')
    CONNECT BY GRANTEE = PRIOR GRANTED_ROLE
) USER_ROLES
GROUP BY GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE
ORDER BY GRANTED_USER, GRANTED_ROLE
;
```

Notice that the query shows `'Direct GRANT'` when the role is granted to the user directly. This stands out a bit better than just showing the user name in the list.

Notice that we still need the `DISTINCT` in the subquery. This is necessary because `TEMPUSER1` gets `TEMP_ROLE4` twice, once from a direct `GRANT` and once from `TEMP_ROLE6`. Without the `DISTINCT`, `TEMP_ROLE4` would show up twice as the source of `TEMP_ROLE3`.

The result looks like this:

```
GRANTED_USER  | GRANTED_ROLE  | ROLE_SOURCE
--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE1    | TEMP_ROLE2
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE2    | Direct GRANT
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE3    | TEMP_ROLE4,TEMP_ROLE5
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE4    | Direct GRANT,TEMP_ROLE6
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE5    | TEMP_ROLE6
TEMPUSER1     | TEMP_ROLE6    | Direct GRANT
TEMPUSER2     | TEMP_ROLE1    | TEMP_ROLE2
TEMPUSER2     | TEMP_ROLE2    | Direct GRANT
```

**For all users**

These queries can be easily adapter to show roles for *all* the users in the database. All that's needed is to change the `START WITH` clause to:

```
START WITH GRANTEE IN (SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS)
```

**For roles**

The queries work equally well if you want to view the roles granted to a particular role. You need only specify the role name as the starting `GRANTEE`. For example,

```
START WITH GRANTEE = 'TEMP_ROLE6'
```

Or for all roles:

```
START WITH GRANTEE IN (SELECT ROLE FROM DBA_ROLES)
```

Comment: TODO: Figure out for user getting their own without DBA privileges. Probably involves `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` (user's directly granted roles) and `ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS` (for getting inherited roles).

Comment: Pete Finnigan has a famous script to do just what is asked.  find_all_privs.sql, at http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm.  That page also lists several other related scripts.  I find the 'who_has' scripts to be useful as well.